# Decrease thickness of a grid line in apex charts

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using Apex charts in the react project, I have implemented a time series chart there I am not able to decrease the "thickness of a grid line" in the line chart.
[Grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muIcZ.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to decrease line thickness of a line chart in apex charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827276/how-to-decrease-line-thickness-of-a-line-chart-in-apex-charts)

Comment: @LoXatoR set the stroke only change the main line. I cant find the option that can help me decrease the thickness of the grid line.

Comment: Aah okay, my bad. Maybe you could try to target with a CSS class?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find any standard ones. With css:

```css
.apexcharts-gridline {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

default value 1px